# clear json server db with axios

Tags: node.js, json, http, axios, json-server

I need to clear/delete a json server database (.json file) before making a post request to populate that with "expenses" data.

I'm getting **"400 - BAD REQUEST"** error when I run the code.

How to "delete all data and then post data" to json server with axios without getting errors?

you can find the code here:
https://github.com/emanuelefavero/json-clear-json-server-db

- after downloading the project:
  `npm i`
- to run the db server: `npm run dev`
- to run the code: `index.js`

Thanks

Comment: Hii Chris, can u please elaborate a question a little more?
and yes, can u share the error message?

Comment: Sure. this is the error message that I get: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emanuelefavero/json-clear-json-server-db/main/error-message.txt

Comment: I'm trying to build a credit card balance app that shows the user the balance for the month. I'm using json-server as a database with api calls from the front-end and backend that GET, DELETE and POST data to DATABASE.json. While implementing the axios backend feature to DELETE all existing data and POST all new data to database.json I get this error message. The code you'll see on github is a test code to recreate that error. I just need to know HOW to DELETE and POST data to db.json using axios (without getting errors). Thanks

Comment: If you have any question, I will answer it